# A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "context" is nullable here

Tags: java, asynchronous, sonarqube, static-analysis

So I have an issue with SonarQube that I can not solve.

```
if (result instanceof AsyncResult) {
    // Make sure handle async has been called
    context.handleAsync();
    Result newResult = context.controllerReturned();
    if (newResult != null) {
        result = newResult;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where is the `context` variable initialized?

Comment: SonarQube is saying that it's possible that context can be null because it couldn't find any initialization to it. Do you want to ignore such errors?

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube claims that `context` may be `null` here. If you know this is incorrect, you could just suppress this warning as a false positive. Otherwise, you should explicitly check if `context` is not `null`:

```
if (result instanceof AsyncResult && context != null) {
    // Here -------------------------^

    // Make sure handle async has been called
    context.handleAsync();
    Result newResult = context.controllerReturned();
    if (newResult != null) {
        result = newResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably here:

```
context.handleAsync();
```

What Sonar says is (given the context [...]) that somewhere in your code, your doing a `null` check on `context` but not in this part:

```
if (null == context) {
  // bla bla bla
}
...
context.handleAsync(); // yes, but context was tested for null, so it can be null.
```

Either recheck the context when using it, either remove the `null` check or fail at the beginning of your method:

```
if (null == context) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("context is null");
}
```

Or better:

```
  void yourMethod(Context context) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(context, "context");
    ... 
  }
```

The `requireNonNull` method is called as a precondition; its only purpose is to check for nulls and provide (if you don't omit) a default message.

Comment: I solved by inserting Objects before context. Is it correct this way? Can you tell me the meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (result instanceof AsyncResult) {
        if (context == null) {
            //appropriate error handling
        } else {
            // Make sure handle async has been called
            context.handleAsync();
            Result newResult = context.controllerReturned();
            if (newResult != null) {
                result = newResult;
            }
        }
}
```

Alternatively you could ensure that when `context` is initialised it can never get value `null`. You could also look into the `@NotNull` annotation from JSR303 if `context` is a method parameter.